# How WordPress encrypt password?

Tags: php, encryption

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to validate WordPress generated password in DB using PHP?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/32004/how-to-validate-wordpress-generated-password-in-db-using-php)

I am working with site that is done with WordPress, and I need to add some parts that are outside WP, and to check user login, but I can't find how WP is encrypting password before it writes it in DB...

I tried with md5 but it's not...

Does anyone know how to check password outside WP, without using it's pluggins/checkers, clear PHP code?

Comment: Closing this as a duplicate of the question @SharkTheDark actually has the ability to accept answers to ...

Comment: you better check here for more informations. http://www.kvcodes.com/2016/09/wordpress-password-hash-generator/

Answer (score 11):

The password encryption library is in /wp-includes/class-phpass.php. It is the [Portable PHP Password hashing framework](http://www.openwall.com/phpass/).

Comment: Can you write some samples how to use it?
Since it's WP Plugin again, not clear PHP as I asked, but if you can write how to use it inside PHP it will be useful...

Comment: This isn't a WordPress plugin. This is a standard PHP class file that is included with the WordPress framework. You just include it in a new PHP file, create an instance, and use it.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you want to use external code to validate usernames/passwords against WP's database.  If that's correct, you're going to spend a lot of time reinventing the wheel.  But for a good example of how to do this using straight PHP, it's a good idea to take a look at the core WP functions that already do it.

Case in point, `wp_check_password()':

```
function wp_check_password($password, $hash, $user_id = '') {
    global $wp_hasher;

    // If the hash is still md5...
    if ( strlen($hash) <= 32 ) {
        $check = ( $hash == md5($password) );
        if ( $check && $user_id ) {
            // Rehash using new hash.
            wp_set_password($password, $user_id);
            $hash = wp_hash_password($password);
        }

        return apply_filters('check_password', $check, $password, $hash, $user_id);
    }

    // If the stored hash is longer than an MD5, presume the
    // new style phpass portable hash.
    if ( empty($wp_hasher) ) {
        require_once ( ABSPATH . 'wp-includes/class-phpass.php');
        // By default, use the portable hash from phpass
        $wp_hasher = new PasswordHash(8, TRUE);
    }

    $check = $wp_hasher->CheckPassword($password, $hash);

    return apply_filters('check_password', $check, $password, $hash, $user_id);
}
```

First, WordPress checks to see if the user's hashed password is still using old-school MD5 for security.  This is to preserve backwards compatibility for updates.  If the password *is* MD5, then WordPress will automatically replace it with a new hash using the new system (the call to `wp_set_password()`).  If it *isn't* MD5, then WP moves on to the newer hashing setup.

First, we include the Portable PHP Hashing Framework (already mentioned by @John Watson in another answer) and create an instance of it, storing it in the global `$wp_hasher` variable.

We then pass in the plaintext password and the hash to verify it against, using the `CheckPassword()` method of the library.

If you want to use this in an external library, you'll have to first `include`/`require` the library, then instantiate it, then pass in your plain text password and its hash.  So some ***untested*** psuedo-code ...

```
function validate_password( $plaintext, $hash ) {
    require_once( 'class-phpass.php' );
    $hasher = new PasswordHash(8, TRUE);

    return $hasher->CheckPassword( $plaintext, $hash );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
require_once( '/path/to/wp-includes/class-phpass.php' );
$wp_hasher = new PasswordHash( 8, TRUE );
$password = 'swordfish';
$hashed_password = $wp_hasher->HashPassword( $password );
```

Comment: It it possible to hash also the password of protected page in database?