# Migrating data from Woocommerce to another webapp

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic, migration

Someone told me today that he'd like me to do an ecommerce application for him, the project is huge so I told him that it would take months or a year. He was fine with that but asked me if I could deploy a simple ecommerce website for him meanwhile.

There are many options out there but I told him I'd pick Wordpress, it's simple and he's fine with it. Upon completion of the application I'm hired to write, is it simple to migrate, data and user accounts to my application assuming I use Mysql/mariadb? Of course the database scheme will be different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple is relative. All the data you need will be in the WordPress database. You'll need to write some code to export the data from the WordPress mySQL/Maria DB, transform it as needed for your scheme, and then import it.

I've done it before, and I would say it's easy for someone who is comfortable with SQL DB and programming.

Comment: Could you tell me what type of password encrption or hashing does wp or woocommerce use? and what do they encrypt or hash? So that I'd follow their way which would make it possible to use the same passwords on both platforms

Comment: Default is to add salt to the password and hash it with 8 passes of MD5.

Asked and answered: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/32004/how-to-validate-wordpress-generated-password-in-db-using-php

Comment: Also, why go through the trouble of creating a custom ecommerce application? Why not stick with WooCommerce (or similar)?

Comment: Is it still md5? that question was asked 5 years ago, md5 is so weak. I can't stick with Woocommerce, the client is asking for custom tools and platforms not available anywhere. They have to be written from scratch but he wants me to install Woocommerce so he has something to start with while I write the software

Comment: Yea, MD5 is still the default.

"Creates a hash of a plain text password. Unless the global $wp_hasher is set, the default implementation uses PasswordHash, which adds salt to the password and hashes it with 8 passes of MD5. MD5 is used by default because it's supported on all platforms. You can configure PasswordHash to use Blowfish or extended DES (if available) instead of MD5 with the $portable_hashes constructor argument or property (see examples)."

https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_hash_password