# How validate usernames/passwords against WP's database?

Tags: password

In wordpress password is encrypted in one format (which i don't know exactly) then saved in database, when i see in db it look in coded form.

I want code in dot net which validated or checked username and password against WP's database is same or not, if it match user go further or not it show msg "wrong username and password "

Is it possible to validated this coded password to external other than wordpress?

I see your this link regarding core WP functions: [How WordPress encrypt password?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/31994/how-wordpress-encrypt-password)

Comment: WordPress uses MD5 encryption to encrypt password. Check your db passwords with [this tool](http://md5encryption.com/). If your dot net supports MD5 you can simply check the dot net way of the [PHP md5 way](http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_string_md5.asp).

Answer (score 2):

Before WordPress 2.5 passwords were simply hashed with md5.

WP 2.5 introduced [phpass](http://www.openwall.com/phpass/), where a password gets hashed and salted several times, in order to be safe against rainbow tables. A littel Googling on phpass and dotnet revealed this post http://davebeer.com/posts/migrating-wordpress-users-to-dotnet/ briefly describing a how to migrating WP users to dotnet.